# Invariant Violation when adding jest.mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Getting this error

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.

After I made icon jest.mock to hide svg details inside my snapshot. I've checked, my imports are OK. Same technique was working before for another components.

I'm using React 16.7 and Jest 24.9.0

My component

```
import { Icons, ToolTip } from '@dev/react';
import React from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
  //some code
  render() {
    let {
      isWarning,
      isExpanded,
      name,
      status,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={styles.title}>
      {isWarning && status !== 'pending' && status !== 'error' && (
        <ToolTip
          arrowEdge="top"
          content={"some contrnt"}
        >
        <Icons.ExclamationTriangle className={styles.icon} />
        </ToolTip>
      )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  //some code
}

export default Header;
```

Tests

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Header from './Header.jsx';

jest.mock('@dev/react', () => ({
  Icons: {
    ExclamationTriangle: 'ReactIcons.ExclamationTriangle',
  }
}));

describe('Warning tooltip', () => {
  let renderSnapshot = renderer.create(elem.getElement()).toJSON();

  it('matches the saved snapshot with warning tooltip', () => {
    const subject = renderComponent({
      isWarning: true,
    });

    expect(renderSnapshot(subject)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

const renderComponent = (props) =>
  shallow(
    <Header
      isExpanded={false}
      name="Some Heading"
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Do you need to mock the `Tooltip` component as well?

Comment: no, its a web component

Comment: Take into account that you are mocking the whole `@dev/react` module. So when you are using the `Tooltip` component you are getting `undefined`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. guys. Good catch. thanks!